# PS5 dualsense controller disconnecting

Tags: controllers, ps5

I tried to [totally disconnect from WiFi](https://www.reddit.com/r/playstation/comments/tqx1i3/ps5_controller_keep_disconnecting/).

That did not help. When I try to connect the second controller it stays connected for 5-10sec and then disconnects. This happens when connecting to an iPhone/PC as well. The controller is fully charged. I did a factory reset as well (holding that back button).

The last thing that I have not tried is a total PS5 refactor.

Any ideas what can help me?

Screenshots:
https://ibb.co/k0KX863
https://ibb.co/ZHMpFQB

Comment: Does it work over USB? Maybe it needs to be charged. Playstation controllers can be picky about charging so I'd suggest charging it with a USB cable connected to a PS4.